# Alguien sabe lo que pasa?

Tags: json

{
"basic": {
"name": "Paula de Camargo Rangel e Lisboa da Costa",
"adress": "Capital-Córdoba-Argentina",
"backImage": "./assets/lencois.jpg",
"image": "./assets/Paula.jpg",
"about": "Soy una persona dinámica, activa, responsable y con facilidad para relacionarme en grupo.Busco una oportunidad de trabajo como Desarrollador Web Full Stack "
},
}

{
"expirence": {
"company": "Claro",
"position": "Vendedora",
"occupation": "Venta de celulares, accesorios. Control de caja, pago de facturas y otras actividades administrativas.",
"image": "./assets/Claro.jpg",

```
    "company": "Centro Cultural Cholo Montironi",
    "position": "Profesora",
    "occupation": "Desarrollo de clases de italiano para adultos, principiantes.",
    "image": "./assets/Casa da cultura.jpg",

    "company": "Guia de Turismo",
    "position": "Autonomo",
    "occupation": "Coordinadora, supervisora de grupos turísticos.",
    "image": "./assets/Guia.png",

    "company": "Facultad São Leopoldo Mandic",
    "position": "Analista administrativa",
    "occupation": "Controle, compras y presupuestos, cuentas por pagar, controles de EPP de los funcionarios y supervisor de los servicios generales y mantenimiento del inventario. Monitoreo de procesos de mantenimiento y verificación de facturas.",
    "image": "./assets/Sao Leopoldo.jpg",

    "company": "MSC Cruceros",
    "position": "Recepcionista Trilingüe",
    "occupation": "Check-in y Check-out de pasajeros de diferentes nacionalidades, solución de problemas relacionados con cabinas de pasajeros, paquetes y otras necesidades. Actualización de la información en el sistema de visas en pasaportes y otras funciones relacionadas con servicios de calidad.",
    "image": "./assets/MSC.jpg",

    "company": "IBM Brasil",
    "position": "Analista de soporte de ventas",
    "occupation": "Apoyo a las operaciones de comercialización de software para África, Europa y el Oriente Medio (EMEA), documentos de la Conferencia en sistemas SAP y base de datos de Lotus Notes.",
    "image": "./assets/IBM.png",

    "company": "Passaredo Linhas Aéreas",
    "position": "Agente de aeropuerto",
    "occupation": "Informes de facturación, emisión de recibos, reservas y venta de pasajes aéreos.",
    "image": "./assets/Passaredo.png",

    "company": "Hotel Luzeiros São Luis",
    "position": "Administración de reservas",
    "occupation": "Propuestas de intermediación para la celebración de lealtad corporativa; suministro de información a los socios, tales como CVC y Booking.com; seguimiento de reserva en línea.",
    "image": "./assets/Luzeiros.png",
},
```

}

Comment: Please post questions in English.

Comment: Hi! Sorry. I would like to know what is wrong here... In the line 9 I have : error end of file expected.

Comment: {
  "name": "Paula de Camargo Rangel e Lisboa da Costa",
  "adress": "Capital-Córdoba-Argentina",
  "backImage": "./assets/lencois.jpg",
  "image": "./assets/Paula.jpg",
  "about": "Soy una persona dinámica, activa, responsable y con facilidad para relacionarme en grupo.Busco una oportunidad de trabajo como Desarrollador Web Full Stack "
}
{
    "expirence":
     [{
       "company": "Claro",
       "position" : "Vendedora",
       "occupation" : "Venta de celulares, accesorios. Control de caja, pago de facturas y otras actividades administrativas.",
       "image" : "./assets/Cla

Answer (score 1):

it means that you json is not valid at all, should be

````
{"data": { "basic": { 
    ... and so on
},
{
        "expirence": [{
                "company": "Claro",
                "position": "Vendedora",
                "occupation": "Venta de celulares, accesorios. Control de caja, pago de facturas y otras actividades administrativas.",
                "image": "./assets/Claro.jpg"
            },
            {
                "company": "Centro Cultural Cholo Montironi",
                "position": "Profesora",
                "occupation": "Desarrollo de clases de italiano para adultos, principiantes.",
                "image": "./assets/Casa da cultura.jpg"
            },
            {
                "company": "Guia de Turismo",
                "position": "Autonomo",
                "occupation": "Coordinadora, supervisora de grupos turísticos.",
                "image": "./assets/Guia.png"
            }, 
                          .... and so on
        ]
    }
}
```
````